# thread safe swift singleton with async/ await and async init

Tags: swift, async-await, thread-safety, singleton, actor

Suppose I have a swift class written like this, how can I ensure the access to the shared() function is thread-safe?

```
class Singleton {
    static private var _shared: Singleton?
    static func shared() async -> Singleton {
        if let shared = _shared {
            return shared
        }
        let shared = await Singleton()
        _shared = shared
        return shared
    }
    
    private init() async {
        // Some mandatory async work
    }
}
```

I know that we can use actors for instances but how do I do this for static members?

I tried to do something like this

```
@globalActor
struct SingletonActor {
    public actor SingletonActor {}
    public static let shared = SingletonActor()
}
```

and then marked the Singleton class as @SingletonActor like

```
@SingletonActor
class Singleton { ... }
```

but that doesn't seem to be working either, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: Practical use case example per comments**

Essentially I want to ensure that all access to firestore first has valid authentication. So I have an AuthRules actor that validates the current user. This is called in the init of the FirestoreServer actor so all functions are ensured to have awaited for valid auth. Here is the practical code, using my unsafe static function access approach.

```
actor AuthRules {
    
    static func shared() async -> AuthRules {
        if let shared = _shared {
            return shared
        }
        let shared = await AuthRules()
        return shared
    }
    static private var _shared: AuthRules?
    
    private init() async {
        await validateAnonymous()
    }
    
    private func signInAnonymously() async {
        do {
            print("AuthBackend.signInAnonymously: Attempting to sign in user anonymously")
            let result = try await Auth.auth().signInAnonymously()
            print("AuthBackend.signInAnonymously: Auth signed in as \(result.user.uid)")
        } catch(let error) {
            print("AuthBackend.signInAnonymously: Unable to sign in user anonymously \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    private func validateAnonymous() async {
        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser, currentUser.isAnonymous {
            print("AuthBackend.validateAnonymous: Auth signed in as \(currentUser.uid)")
        } else {
            await signInAnonymously()
        }
    }
}

actor FirestoreServer {
    
    static func server() async -> FirestoreServer {
        if let server = _server {
            return server
        }
        let server = await FirestoreServer()
        return server
    }
    static private var _server: FirestoreServer?
    
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    private let authRules: AuthRules
    
    private init() async {
        authRules = await AuthRules.shared()
    }
    
    /* several async functions that communicate with firestore through db */
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but that doesn't seem to be working either"? Can you show a [mcve] of what happens with this code?

Comment: Use an AsyncStream

Comment: Hi everyone yeah I've changed my actual code so I don't need to deal with this issue but I'll update the original question with a more practical example anyways

Comment: Hey @Sweeper I guess a minimal reproducible example would be just making repeated calls to a firestore using this firestoreserver class I added from different threads?

Comment: Also I have added the practical example @Rob

Comment: I would not have `shared` initiate and `await` the `validateAnonymous` at all. The `shared` name connotes “give me a reference to that shared instance”. (And it’s a little curious to then turn around and save that reference in a property … that’s the point of `shared`, to give you convenient access to that singleton from anywhere in your codebase). Personally, I would adopt the traditional singleton pattern, not have its `init` call `validateAnonymous`, not have `FirestoreServer` keep that reference, and then have `FirestoreServer` then just call `await AuthRules.shared.validateAnonymous()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example (a `class` with `async` method initializer and `async` rendition of `shared()`) is definitely not thread safe. And the property wrapper approach won’t work, either.

If you really needed to have a singleton with an `async` initializer, I guess you could do something like:

```swift
actor Foo {
    static private var task: Task<Foo, Never>?
    
    static func shared() async -> Foo {
        if let task {
            return await task.value
        }
        let task = Task { await Foo() }
        self.task = task
        return await task.value
    }
    
    private init() async {
        // something asynchronous, with an `await`
    }
}
```

Needless to say, this obviously lacks the elegance and simplicity of the standard singleton pattern:

```swift
final class Foo {
    static let shared = Foo()
    
    private init() {
        // standard synchronous initializer
    }
}
```

The idea behind the first snippet is to use a `actor` to eliminate data races, but because actors are reentrant, we `await` a `Task` for the original instantiation.

It works, but I am hard pressed to think of a practical example where I would ever want to use something as cumbersome as this.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer I really appreciate the help. I ended up just rewriting the solution for my specific use case so I did not have to deal with this issue (like you said pretty cumbersome) but your insight has been helpful!

Comment: Okay sike I actually decided to use your approach because my other method was pretty bad too, so thank you!